How to generate a count of 0 in a group by with multiple columns with count(*)
I am desperately trying to figure out how to do something that is probably simply.
When I run this query, the output only counts records where there is a value greater than 0.
select year, code, type, count(*) as count
from  #senatetest2
group by year, code, type
order by year, code, type

It will give me:
Year  Code   Type   Count
2020   A      Z      1
2020   B      Y      2 

When I want:
Year  Code   Type   Count
2020   A      Z      1
2020   B      Y      2 
2020   C      X      0

All case when queries use a column, however, I am not counting a column, I am counting all (*). Is there any way to get the count column to count and return an output of zero?
I have to do this by tomorrow for work (it's my day off) and I cannot get figured out.
Thank you so much in advance.

How you are determining that 2020-C-X should be a row with a count of zero? Why not have other rows with zeros such as 2020-C-Z and 2020-C-Y and 2020-A-X and 2020-A-Y, etc.

All I am trying to do is make it so I don't have to create a row in Excel and manually enter a value of zero. It's for a chart for my bosses and they want all the values to show whether there is 0 or > 0

But that didn't answer the question. How do you know a value of 0 should exist for any Year-Code-Type combination? Do you want ALL combinations? So if you have 3 years, 3 codes and 3 types, you have 3x3x3 = 27 rows? Is that what you are looking for?

How come you don't want (2020,. D, W, 0) etc too?

A [mcve] is supposed to include both sample table data and the expected result.

Sorry there is no sample data - it's how many times a combination of columns occur in a dataset. There is no sample data to input into a table

It can't make up data that doesn't exists, therefore you would need a driver table that contains the combination of Year|Code|Type that you would want in your output.
Something like:
CREATE TABLE driver (year int, code char(1), type char(1));
INSERT INTO DRIVER VALUES (2020,'A','Z');
INSERT INTO DRIVER VALUES (2020,'B','Y');
INSERT INTO DRIVER VALUES (2020,'C','X');


SELECT driver.Year, driver.Code, driver.Type, count(st.type) as count 
FROM driver 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN #senatetest2 st 
      ON driver.year = st.year
      AND driver.code=st.code
      AND driver.type = st.type;


Ok thank you then I cannot do it. Thank you for your response. It sounds like what I want isn't possible with this query. I am simply counting the number of rows in a dataset and I want a zero where there is not a combination of those rows. It's helpful to not keep querying for it. Thanks again.

@lpd983  Without knowing sample data and more on the expected results, I wouldnt say it's impossible yet.  We just need to better understand the rules.  If C exists somewhere it can be built using cross join as isolated has asked.

To me, it sounds like you may want a Cartesian product, which is basically a row for every possible combination based on the values you have in n-number of columns. In this case, we'll pretend that your cartesian product is based on year, code and type.
Using sample data which has 3 years, 3 codes and 3 types, we should expect 27 rows returned. We can use a CTE to generate those combinations by using CROSS JOIN, then select from the CTE and then LEFT JOIN back to your data.
create table senatetest2 (
  year integer, 
  code varchar(5), 
  type varchar(5), 
  order_id integer
  );

insert into senatetest2 values 
(2020, 'A', 'Z', 1), 
(2020, 'B', 'Y', 2), 
(2020, 'B', 'Y', 3), 
(2021, 'C', 'X', 4), 
(2022, 'A', 'Z', 5);

with combos as (
  select distinct x.year, y.code, z.type
  from senatetest2 x
  cross join senatetest2 y
  cross join senatetest2 z
)
select 
 c.year, 
 c.code, 
 c.type, 
 count(t.year) as count --count t.anything here
from combos c
left join senatetest2 t
  on c.year = t.year
 and c.code = t.code 
 and c.type = t.type
group by 
 c.year, 
 c.code, 
 c.type 






year
code
type
count




2020
A
X
0


2020
A
Y
0


2020
A
Z
1


2020
B
X
0


2020
B
Y
2


2020
B
Z
0


2020
C
X
0


2020
C
Y
0


2020
C
Z
0


2021
A
X
0


2021
A
Y
0


2021
A
Z
0


2021
B
X
0


2021
B
Y
0


2021
B
Z
0


2021
C
X
1


2021
C
Y
0


2021
C
Z
0


2022
A
X
0


2022
A
Y
0


2022
A
Z
1


2022
B
X
0


2022
B
Y
0


2022
B
Z
0


2022
C
X
0


2022
C
Y
0


2022
C
Z
0



fiddle

Seems reasonable; but question is too vague to know. and given desired results, however the comment on the accepted answer makes me think a Cartesian filtered somehow is what they want.
